# Tapestry: How can I keep the sort functionality in a custom Grid header?

Tags: grid, tapestry

I need to customise the header text on a Tapestry Grid column. This code does just that, but it removes the sort functionality

```
<table class="table table-striped" t:type="grid" t:source="data"
    t:rowsPerPage="50" t:pagerPosition="bottom">

    <p:specialHeader>Custom header</p:specialHeader>

</table>
```

[image: Grid with custom header]

How can I restore the sort functionality to this custom header?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need just a text in grid header you can use message bundle for this:

```
special-label=Custom header
```

Comment: but that changes the label everywhere in the page, not just the grid component. in my case not an option.